# Use flickity in Blazor server

Tags: blazor

I'm trying to use the flickity js library (https://flickity.metafizzy.co/) in my Blazor server application. For some reason, I can't get it to work, even though I tried a lot of different scenarios.

This is how it looks right now:

1. I added the CSS and javascript files in _Host.chtml

```
<link href="https://npmcdn.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.css" rel="stylesheet" />

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

2. I added the code for the carousel in the page:

```
 <div class="main-carousel">
        <div class="carousel-cell">1</div>
        <div class="carousel-cell">2</div>
        <div class="carousel-cell">3</div>

    </div>
```

3. In _Host.chtml I then created this function:

```
 window.initF = () => {
            $('.main-carousel').flickity({
                // options
                cellAlign: 'left',
                contain: true
            });
        }
```

4. In the page I then try to initiate it:

```
@inject IJSRuntime js

@functions{
    protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstrender)
    {
        if (firstrender)
        {
            await js.InvokeAsync<object>("initF");

            firstrender = false;
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason, it doesn't work.

Someone that has an idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work fine for me.

I have tried it in `blazor` fiddle and took the CSS from the library's website, and works similar to the demo they have there.
[See attachment](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/jx38mbni)

Can you remove one line from your code where you assign `firstrender` value, as this is automatically handled:

```cs
protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstrender)
{
    if (firstrender)
    {
        await js.InvokeAsync<object>("initF");

        // firstrender = false; <- remove this assignment
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Got it to wxork!